# Text Axis Labels for Grouped/Stacked Bar chart in NVD3

Tags: nvd3.js

I've been trying to get the x axis to display a text axis label. The example is here https://jsfiddle.net/z4aZ4/859/
I'd like "Question 1" displayed on the x axis. At the moment "Nan" is displayed.

```
var data = 
[
{
"key": "Yes",
"color": "#d67777",
"values": [
  {
    "x" : "Question 1" ,
    "y" : 70
  } ,
  {
    "x" : "Question 2" ,
    "y" : 65
  } 
    ]
  },
  {
"key": "No",
"color": "#4f99b4",
"values": [
  {
    "x" : "Question 1" ,
    "y" : 30
  } ,
  {
    "x" : "Question 2" ,
    "y" : 35
  } 
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to change the tick format to load your labels.
On the addGraph function:

Replace

```
.tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
```

With

```
.tickFormat(function(d) { return d; });
```

Also so that a label will show up for each column you'll have to set reduceXTicks False:

```
var chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
.reduceXTicks(false);
```